# Increment Added <tr> id

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table with a single row and several columns, with an add row (Add Item) button which clones said table row. The table row has a select drop-down menu full of item SKU's, which onChange will pull up the SKU's Product Name, Cubic Meters, and Price from our database and display it in the empty columns.

The problem is when I add a row and select a sku on the new row, the information on the first row changes instead of the row that it's on.

Example:

[image: Purchase order form. One Row]

[image: Purchase order form. Two Rows]

Here is the Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Adds Cloned Table Row to the Form
    function onClickAdd() {
        var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
        var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
        tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
            }
    // Retrieves Product Name from db
    function getProdName(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("tableRow").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("prodName").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getProd.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    // Retrieves Cubic Meters from db
    function getCBM(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("tableRow").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("cbm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getCBM.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    // Retrieves Price from db
    function getPrice(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("tableRow").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getPrice.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the Table:

```
 <table width = 100%>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Add Item</th>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>CBM</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Net Price</th>
                <!--Not Functional <th>Delete</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php 


            echo "<tr id='tableRow'>";
            echo "<td width = 10%><input type = 'submit' value = 'Add Item' onClick='Javascript:onClickAdd()'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10%>";
            echo "<select name = 'item' onchange = 'getProdName(this.value);getCBM(this.value);getPrice(this.value)'>";

                // Retrieves SKUs from db and populates Select Options
                $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '****');
                mysql_select_db('Database'); 
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT sku FROM inventory");

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['sku'] . '">'.$row['sku'].'</option>';
                    }

            echo "</select>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 30% id = 'prodName'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10% id = 'cbm'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10% id = 'qty'><input type = 'text' size = '5'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10% id = 'cost'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10% id = 'netCost'></td>";
            // Not Functional echo "<td width = 10%><input type = 'submit' value = 'Delete'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Total:</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td width = 30%></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10% id = 'totalCBM'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10%></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10%></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10% id = 'totalCost'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 10%></td>";
            echo "</tr>";


        ?>

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Is it possible to have each Select Dropdown correspond to the row that it is on?

Comment: It's because when you clone, id of new element and old element remains same so it causes duplicate id issue.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response!! Do you  have any recommendations on how to eliminate the duplicate id issue? I was thinking about incrementing the id, but still coming up with a way of executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the function in Jquery, finally got satisfying results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Purchase Order Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
    form{
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    form input, button{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Retrieves Product Name from db based on selected sku
    function getProdName(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("prodName").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getProd.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    // Retrieves Cubic Meters from db based on selected sku
    function getCBM(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("cbm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getCBM.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    // Retrieves Price from db based on selected sku
    function getPrice(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getPrice.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //add-row
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            //sku
            var sku = $("#sku").val();          
            //prodName
            var prodName = $("#prodName").text();
            //cbm
            var cbm = $("#cbm").text();
            //qty
            var qty = $("#qty").val();
            //price
            var price = $("#price").text();
            //netPrice
            var netPrice = $("#netPrice").text();
            //markup
            var markup = "<tr><td width=10%><input type='checkbox' name='record' size='1'></td><td width=10%>" + sku + "</td><td width=40%>" + prodName + "</td><td width=10%>" + cbm + "</td><td width=10%>" + qty + "</td><td width=10%>" + price + "</td><td width=10%>" + netPrice + "</td></tr>";
            $("#ledger").append(markup);    
        });

        // Find and remove selected table rows
        //record
        $(".delete-row").click(function(){
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table width=100%>
        <tr>
            <th width=10%>SKU</th>
            <th width=40%>Product Name</th>
            <th width=10%>CBM</th>
            <th width=10%>Qty</th>
            <th width=10%>Price</th>
            <th width=10%>Net Price</th>
            <th width=10%>Add</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <!--name/sku-->
            <td><?php

            echo "<select name='item' id='sku' onchange='getProdName(this.value);getCBM(this.value);getPrice(this.value)'>";

            $connection = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password');
            mysql_select_db('ADI'); 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT sku FROM inventory");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['sku'] . '">'.$row['sku'].'</option>';
                }

            echo "</select>";

            ?></td>     
        <!--email/prodName-->
        <td id="prodName"></td>
        <!--cbm-->
        <td id="cbm"></td>
        <!--qty-->
        <td><input type="text" id="qty" placeholder="Quantity" size="3"></td>
        <!--price-->
        <td id="price"></td>
        <!--netPrice-->
        <td id="netPrice"></td>
        <!--add-row-->
        <td><input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row" onclick="Javascript: getProdName(); getCBM(); getPrice();"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <table id="ledger">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width=10%>Select</th>
                <th width=10%>SKU</th>
                <th width=40%>ProdName</th>
                <th width=10%>CBM</th>
                <th width=10%>Quantity</th>
                <th width=10%>Unit Price</th>
                <th width=10%>Net Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--Delete-Row button-->
    <button type="button" class="delete-row" >Delete Row</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well duplicate id's is not allowed in html whereas duplicate classes can be allowed so you can give the classes like `cost-1` and `1` being dynamic.

now you need to program your logic to write into the correct class that way.

Hope this helps,